# My variable in component re-render after refresh page. App with POSTS, COMMENTS and LIKES

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rendering, mern

I have the problem with my component. I'm creating a POST application with comments and likes. I have the problem with likes. Everything looks good but when I click like my infromation about how many likes and the like-symbols don't re-render. When I refresh the page it's working. I have the home page when I display all the posts

```
const Home = () => {
const { posts, dispatch } = usePostContext()
const { user } = useAuthContext()

useEffect(() => {

    const fetchPosts = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/api/posts', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`
            }
        })

        const json = await response.json()
        dispatch({type: "SET_POSTS", payload: json})
    }


    if (user) {
        fetchPosts()
    }

}, [dispatch, user])

return (
    <div className='home'>
        {posts.length > 0 ? posts.map(post => (
            <PostDetails key={post._id} post={post}/>
        )) : <h1 className='no-posts-info'>You don't have any posts yet</h1>}
    </div>
)
```

}`

in my db my post model has array with likes.

```
`const PostDetails = ({ post }) => {
const { user } = useAuthContext()
const { dispatch } = usePostContext()



const username = user.email.split('@')[0]

const handleClick = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/posts/' + post._id, {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`
        }
})

const json = await response.json()

if (response.ok) {
    dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_POST', payload: json })
}

}

return (
    <div className="post">
        <div><h1>{post.title}</h1> {username === post.author && <span onClick={handleClick} className='delete-button material-symbols-outlined'>delete</span>}</div>
        <p>{post.content}</p>
        <div>
            <div>
                <Like post={post}/>
                <p>{formatDistanceToNow(new Date(post.createdAt), { addSuffix: true })}</p>
            </div>
            <p>{post.author}</p>
        </div>
        <CommentDetails _id={post._id}/>
        <AddComment _id={post._id}/>
    </div>
)
```

}`

and here in my component PostDetails I have the component Like which looks like

```
const Like = ({ post }) => {
const { user } = useAuthContext()
const { dispatch } = usePostContext()

const likeHandler = async () => {
    
    const response = await fetch('/api/posts/like/' + post._id, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user_email: user.email
        }),
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })

    const json = await response.json()

    if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_POST', payload: json})
    }
}

const unlikeHandler = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/posts/unlike/' + post._id, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user_email: user.email
        }),
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })

    const json = await response.json()

    if (response.ok) {
        dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_POST', payload: json})
    }

}
return (
    <div>
        {!post.likes.includes(user.email) && <span onClick={likeHandler} className="heart material-symbols-outlined">
            favorite
        </span>}
        {post.likes.includes(user.email) && <span onClick={unlikeHandler} className="red heart material-symbols-outlined">
            favorite
        </span>}
        {post.likes.length > 1 ? <p className="like-info">{post.likes.length } likes</p> : <p className="like-info">{post.likes.length} like</p>}
    </div>
)
```

}`

I don't know what is wrong but I cannot re-render only number of likes and like-symbols to be red.

Has someone any idea?

Comment: Check if Like Component is re-rendering after like/dislike. If it is then there must be a problem while updating state.

Comment: Like component is re-rendering when i like and unlike

Comment: Then most likely the state update is not happening as expected. You can debug that by putting console logs inside "UPDATE_POST" case in reducer. See what info is retrieved from API response that you are going to update. Does the likes fields coming as expected?

Comment: No, thank you BRO! I made mistake when I sent my post response from backend because I sent old POST, before updated. Thanks!